# SQL - Double and statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to select some data from two tables, where some conditions has to be true. I am trying to join to AND/OR statements together.

```
select 
    a.token, a.fixed_expire, b.token, b.username, COUNT(DISTINCT a.token) adcount, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.username) clickcount
    from advertisements a 
    JOIN advertisement_clicks b ON b.token=a.token
    where a.status='2' AND (a.clicks_left > 0 OR a.daily ='1' OR a.fixed='1' AND(a.fixed_expire>'2'))
```

So, above query doesn't work. My question is, how can I join the `OR a.fixed='1' AND(a.fixed_expire>'2')` inside the original `AND` operation?

If `a.fixed='1'` then it should check for `a.fixed_expire>2`

Comment: Put parentheses around `a.fixed = '1' AND a.fixed_expire > '2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a.clicks_left > 0 OR a.daily ='1' OR a.fixed='1' )AND(a.fixed_expire>'2')

You should group OR statements